# Add Same Class To Muliple Divs Using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using Bootstrap and I have a form which has 2 states (Entry & Confirm).

When the form is in a state of 'Entry' the `<div>` should have a class of `form-group`

**Entry HTML shown below**

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-2 control-label">From</label>
     <div id="FromDiv" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">[!From_DropDownList]</div>
     <div id="FromErrorDiv" class="col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-7">[!From_DropDownList_Error]</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-2 control-label">To</label>
     <div id="ToDiv" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">[!To_DropDownList]</div>
     <div id="ToErrorDiv" class="col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-7">[!To_DropDownList_Error]</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-2 control-label">Amount</label>
     <div id="AmountDiv" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">[!Amount_TextBox]</div>
     <div id="AmountErrorDiv" class="col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-7">[!Amount_Error]</div>
</div>
```

When the form is in a state of 'Confirm' the `<div>` should have a class of `row`

**Confirm HTML shown below**

```
<div class="row">
     <label class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-2 control-label">From</label>
     <div id="FromDiv" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">[!From_DropDownList]</div>
     <div id="FromErrorDiv" class="col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-7">[!From_DropDownList_Error]</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
     <label class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-2 control-label">To</label>
     <div id="ToDiv" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">[!To_DropDownList]</div>
     <div id="ToErrorDiv" class="col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-7">[!To_DropDownList_Error]</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
     <label class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-2 control-label">Amount</label>
     <div id="AmountDiv" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">[!Amount_TextBox]</div>
     <div id="AmountErrorDiv" class="col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-7">[!Amount_Error]</div>
</div>
```

If I add an `id` to the `div` and handle it in my JavaScript, I can only get it to add the `class` to the first `div` and not the rest although if I F12 the webpage, all the rows have the same `id`

Whats the best way of doing this so that I don't have to add a JavaScript line of code for each `div` `id`

Is there some sort of add to all functionality in JavaScript I can use to cut down on code?

Below is what I have come up with for my HTML

```
<div id="RowDivClass">
      <label class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-2 control-label">From</label>
      <div id="FromDiv" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">[!From_DropDownList]</div>
      <div id="FromErrorDiv" class="col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-7">[!From_DropDownList_Error]</div>
 </div>
 <div id="RowDivClass">
      <label class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-2 control-label">To</label>
      <div id="ToDiv" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">[!To_DropDownList]</div>
      <div id="ToErrorDiv" class="col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-7">[!To_DropDownList_Error]</div>
 </div>
 <div id="RowDivClass">
      <label class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-2 control-label">Amount</label>
      <div id="AmountDiv" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">[!Amount_TextBox]</div>
      <div id="AmountErrorDiv" class="col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-7">[!Amount_Error]</div>
 </div>
```

My JavaScript I have for the `onclick` of my 'Create' button is

```
function RegCashMoveCreate(txt) {
     document.getElementById('RowDivClass').className = "form-group";
};
```

My JavaScript I have for the page state for 'Confirm' is

```
<% if (state == "Confirm") { %>
     document.getElementById('RowDivClass').className = "row";
<% } %>
```

Basically I want to add the same `class` to a number of `div` dependant upon the page state

Comment: An ID should not be assigned to more than one element. This is why it's only finding and modifying the first-found element.

Comment: @WesFoster I no an Id should be unique but it all I could think off at the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed my ID's (as I know they should have all been unique) and added `class="form-group"` back to each `div` then decided that I had to go with JQuery as shown below

```
$('.form-group').removeClass('form-group').addClass('row');
```

This replaces all `class="form-group"` with `class="row"` in one.

Answer (score 0):

Use classes instead of IDs. An ID should not be assigned to more than one element. This is why it's only finding and modifying the first-found element.

**Entry HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-2 control-label">From</label>
     <div id="FromDiv" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">[!From_DropDownList]</div>
     <div id="FromErrorDiv" class="col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-7">[!From_DropDownList_Error]</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-2 control-label">To</label>
     <div id="ToDiv" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">[!To_DropDownList]</div>
     <div id="ToErrorDiv" class="col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-7">[!To_DropDownList_Error]</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-2 control-label">Amount</label>
     <div id="AmountDiv" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">[!Amount_TextBox]</div>
     <div id="AmountErrorDiv" class="col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-7">[!Amount_Error]</div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**
Note, since there are multiple elements with the same class name, you need to loop through and apply it to each one:

```
function RegCashMoveCreate(txt) {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("form-group");
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
    {
        elements[i].className = "row";
    }
};
```

More information on `getElementsByClassName()` can be found here: [W3Schools getElementsByClassName()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp)

Comment: This isn't doing all the 'Form-Group' it's doing every other one, so it changes the 1st 'div' to 'Row', leaves the 2nd 'div' as 'Form-group', changes the 3rd 'div' to 'Row', leaves the 4th 'div' as 'Form-Group' and then changes the 5th div to 'Row'

Comment: Try setting the className to `elements[i].className = "form-group row"` and see if that helps.

Comment: I have just had a play on the link you provided and created another class and amending the JavaScript to what you provided and it does the same and the suggestion you have made also doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

It should work. Use this script

```
<script>
    function RegCashMoveCreate() 
     {
        var abcElements = document.querySelectorAll('.form-group');

        for (var i = 0; i < abcElements.length; i++)
        {
           abcElements[i].className = 'row';
        }
     }
</script>
```